# Entering a matrix using input

Tags: python, matrix

I want to input a matrix in the following form:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I have tried this code

```
m1=[]
r,c=input().split(" ")
print(r,"and",c)
for x in range (0,r):
    for y in range (0,c):
        m1[x][y]=input().split(" ")
    print("\n")    
print (m1)
```

but get an exception instead:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Well, your `m1` list is empty. You can't assign to indices that are not there. You need to use `.append()` or `.extend()` or a list comprehension to add indices.

Comment: m1=[]
 r,c=input().split(" ")
 print(r,"and",c)
 for x in range (0,int(r)):
    for y in range (0,int(c)):
        m1.append(input().split(" "))
    print("\n")    
 print (m1) its taking continuously inputs not printing matrix